How to wire lutron 3-way LED dimmable switch
I would like to wire a new installation of a lutron 3-way led dimmable switch for use in 2 locations.  I presently have 1 switch installed and it works in that setup as a single-pole application.
I have it wired such that s1 (switch 1) has the left brass terminal going to the light black and the copper terminal going to the power black, neutrals and ground are connected together.
This is the documentation for the switch:
https://assets.lutron.com/a/documents/368-4493_page_7.pdf
I want to add an additional switch location.  I am not following the diagram.  Can I merely run a 3-wire (12/3 in my case) from the existing switch location to the new switch location?  The first switch location has power and the light.  From the diagram, it seems like the power and light cannot be together?
How do I go from how I presently have it wired to a 3-way setup?
If the switch on the left is s1 and the switch on the right is s2, then:

disconnect light black from s1
connect light black to s2 copper terminal, which color wire (there aren't any left)?
connect s1 left brass terminal to s2 left brass terminal via red wire
connect s1 right brass terminal to s2 brass terminal, black wire
connect neutral and grounds

From the diagram, it appears that I either have the power or light connected to 1 switch, but not both as there wouldn't be enough wires.  So, I need to either run power to s2 or the light to s2 along with a 3-wire between s1 and s2.

If the light connection is indeed at the existing first switch then the common wire terminal at the added switch is used to bring the circuit back to the first box for the light.
I'll mark up the diagram and show how that looks.

The gray rectangles represent the electrical boxes. You need to run 14-4 w/GND between the two switch boxes due to the fact that current electrical code requires a neutral at each electrical box but in your case this would be just capped off unless you were using a smart switch there. The things represent the points where connections are made via wire nuts or WAGO type connectors.
Also the safety ground and neutral are not to be connected together so correct that mistake. Safety ground and neutrals are to be run separately all the way back to the main power panel.

Ok, that makes sense that I would need a 4-wire cable then or instead pull the power to the other switch and then do a 3-wire cable as normal.  I didn't mean neutral and ground were connected together, I meant that ground to ground neutral to neutral.  Yes, they're connected to the same bar in the main panel, but are separate until the main panel.

As 4-wire cable is expensive and has fewer options, wouldn't it be most cost effective to merely bring power or the light to the other box and then just run a 3-wire cable as normally between the 2 switches?  My main question was just that, power and load must be on different switches to utilize a 3-wire cable, if they're on the same switch, then a 4-wire cable must be used.

Being pedantic the light is not "on the same switch". It is in the same electrical box. It would be your choice if you run the 3-wire cable from the light to the 2nd switch or run 4-wire cable. It comes down to labor work to re-route the light wire as they are often some distance from the switch and hidden in the walls and ceiling. If the routing paths are accessible then by all means use 14-3wGND to the 2nd switch and re-route the light wire.

You also have the option of using individual THNN type conductors in conduit or other approved type of raceway. This may be a good choice over 14-4/wGND cable.

Ok, I was originally thinking that, but then again, I would need to run a conduit.  I think the best option in my case is to merely rewire it because I don't want to be a black sheep here.  I have enough 12/2 wire to rewire the light and enough 12/3 wire to connect the switches, so might as well do it the common way.
